# Using Ctrl-<ArrowKey> and Home/End with (u)rxvt

Tags: terminal, urxvt, rxvt

I'm using `rxvt-unicode` for it's the less flawed terminal emulator I know.

I'm looking for using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> and <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd> to navigate through command line text, to emulate the behavior of all other modern text fields.

Could anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: urxvt doesn't send the same sequence of characters for those keys as xterm, but it can be configured to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Something else is eating your keys, the window manager most likely. Go to settings and set virtual desktop switching to something else.

The behavior you are describing is the default (readline commands).

```
$ bind -p| grep -E 'forward|backward-word' |grep -v "^#"
"\e\e[D": backward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
"\e[1;3D": backward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word           #<---- this
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\eb": backward-word
"\C-f": forward-char
"\eOC": forward-char
"\e[C": forward-char
"\C-s": forward-search-history
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\eOc": forward-word
"\e[1;3C": forward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word            #<----- and here
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\ef": forward-word
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```